# changing content of fs.createReadstream

Tags: node.js, express, pipe, filestream

I have requirement such that I am reading a file on express request as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
var express = require("express");
app = express();

app.get('/getdata', function (req, res) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream('myFileLocation');// this location contains encrypted file
  let tempVariable = [];
  stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        tempVariable += chunk;
    });
stream.on('end', function () {
    *****here I read tempVariable and using it I decrypt the file content and output a buffer (say,finalBuffer)****

})
stream.on('error', function (error) {
        res.writeHead(404, 'Not Found');
        res.end();
    });
stream.pipe(res);
```

So what should I do to make the 'finalBuffer' readable on request,in other words, how to pipe the finalBuffer data with **res**(response).

Comment: If you want to use a stream, then you would create a stream transform that decrypts the data incrementally.  That would allow you to pipe it to the response.  The way you have it now, the content has already been sent by the time you get to the `end` event.  Here's a [good article](http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the way for creating read stream from a Buffer using stream of node js. 
I got exact solution from [here](https://github.com/gagle/node-streamifier/blob/master/lib/index.js).
I have just put a little bit code like

```
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const path = require('path');
var express = require("express");
app = express();

app.get('/getdata', function (req, res) { // getdata means getting decrypted data


fs.readFile(file_location, function read(err, data) {
   // here I am performing my decryption logic which gives output say 
   //"decryptedBuffer"
   var stream = require("./index.js");
   stream.createReadStream(decryptedBuffer).pipe(res);

})
})
```

```
// index.js
'use strict';

var util = require('util');
var stream = require('stream');

module.exports.createReadStream = function (object, options) {
  return new MultiStream (object, options);
};

var MultiStream = function (object, options) {
  if (object instanceof Buffer || typeof object === 'string') {
    options = options || {};
    stream.Readable.call(this, {
      highWaterMark: options.highWaterMark,
      encoding: options.encoding
    });
  } else {
    stream.Readable.call(this, { objectMode: true });
  }
  this._object = object;
};

util.inherits(MultiStream, stream.Readable);

MultiStream.prototype._read = function () {
  this.push(this._object);
  this._object = null;
};
```

If anybody has some issue with this please comment I will try my best to make him/her understood my code snippet.